# Silverlight : disable copy/paste/cut operations on textbox

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have requirement to disable copy/paste/cut operations on a textbox. For this purpose I inherited the Textbox and created MyTextbox and had the KeyDown event overriden with the following code

```
if (!(e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right || e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Tab))
{
    if ((e.Key == Key.C || e.Key == Key.X || e.Key == Key.V) &&
                     (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

and then used this textbox. This textbox now prevents copy/paste/cut operations.

I am trying to acheive this same purpose using Behaviors.For this purpose I have created a behavior. The code is as under

```
public class MyTextboxBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            this.AssociatedObject.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(AssociatedObject_KeyDown);
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right || e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Tab))
            {
                if ((e.Key == Key.C || e.Key == Key.X || e.Key == Key.V) &&
                     (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and have added this behavior to Textbox as under

```
<TextBox>
     <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <CustomControl:MyTextboxBehavior></CustomControl:MyTextboxBehavior>
     </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED JUNE 24**

In WPF, you would be able to capture the *CTRL* + *X/C/V* key presses at the `PreviewKeyDown` event, and then you would be able to suppress these functions in your text box.

In Silverlight *Preview* methods are not available, so here it is not an option. The `TextBox` control also has built-in handling of the clipboard actions copy and paste `CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V` (see [Clipboard class remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)), so it is not straightforward to suppress these actions.

There is an attempt for an SL3 project [here](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1961-restrict-clipboard-shortcuts-textbox-silverlight.aspx) where the `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` event handlers are overridden in a class deriving from `TextBox`. The implementation calls the `base` methods which are obviously not accessible in the `Behavior` implementation, so a straightforward implementation of the *copy* and *paste* suppression in the `TextBox` via behaviors does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (e.Key == Key.Ctrl)
            Clipboard.SetText(string.Empty);
```

Comment: Please, consider providing an explanation to the answer.